# Silverlight4 with RhinoMock

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, rhino-mocks

Does RhinoMocks work with SilverLight 4?

If not, are there any alternatives?

I know that RhinoMock 3.5 has been ported to SilverLight, but I cannot find the dll file, because I every time get redirected to http://ayende.com/blog from any links I get.

(Offical page: http://ayende.com/blog/3843/rhino-mocks-3-5-silverlight)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any recent version. You could go with [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) instead.

Comment: Does it work well with silverlight 4? Because on the main page it is said to work with 3.5

Comment: @kori0129: Well, the latest download is named Moq.4.0 and contains assemblies for Silverlight 4, so I guess it works with SL4. However, I haven't used it myself, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... I got it, but now I cannot find the link where I downloaded it, maybe worth to check if it's available on NuGet?